# /usr/bin/find is needed but I can't locate the package to install it

Tags: find, software-installation, docker, amazon-linux

I am trying to set up a Docker container that runs from the base amazonlinux and install the Oracle version of the jdk but it keep failing on with the error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/find is needed by jdk1.8.0_144-2000:1.8.0_144-fcs.x86_64
```

I have tried yum installing find but no packages of that name exist. I have tried googling but using the word "find" is not returning any helpful information. not sure what I am missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/usr/bin/find` is a part if `findutils` package in RHEL and systems based on it (which amazonlinux is). So you have to install `findutils` to fix your dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can check what package provides a particular executable with

```
yum provides /usr/bin/find
```

I get (on Fedora 24):

```
 $ yum provides /usr/bin/find
 ...
 findutils-1:4.6.0-7.fc24.x86_64 : The GNU versions of find utilities (find and xargs)
 Repo        : @System
 ...
```